# I have to display 'location' with respective to the 'latitude' and 'longitude'. Got the desired location printed in the console but not getting saved

Tags: python, django, rest

I tried many approaches including SerializerMethodField and didn't work.
I want to print the location in the result with respect to the latitude and longitude from the models.

Models.py

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(default=Point(0,0),geography=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(blank=True,max_digits=9,decimal_places=6,default=None,null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(blank=True,max_digits=9,decimal_places=6,default=None,null=True)
```

Serializer.py

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerProfile
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
class CustomerView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        query = CustomerProfile.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(query, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request,data,format=None):
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            lat=getattr(data,"latitude")
            lon= getattr(data,"longitude")
            lat_1 = float(str(lat))
            lon_1 = float(str(lon))
            print(lon_1)
            if lat_1 and lon_1:
                location = Point((lat_1, lon_1), srid=4326)
                print(location)
                if location:
                    loc=getattr(data,"location")
                    print(loc)
                    loc=location
                    Serializer.save()
            return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
        return Response({"message":"Customer registration failed!!","data":serializer.data}, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly `print(location)` is the one you want to save and `print(loc)` is also in the form but you don't actually want to use it, as you already have lat and long separated, right?

I see two problems in your code:

`loc=location` does not work as you expect it. loc will be first your data.location, and then the new value, but it won't set data.location to the new value. I'm not sure if it works but you could try something like: `setattr(data, "location", location)` so set the new value.

The other one is `Serializer.save()`, which is capitalized, and in python capitalization does matter: `serializer.save()` would be right.
A quick sidenote: You should use a linter that directly checks your syntax and variable names. It should have shown you that this variable isn't set. PyCharm is a great editor to work with python.

I think you can pass the variable to the save method like this:
`serializer.save(location=location)`